# Is GSON performing safe serialization?

Tags: android, json, gson

If a JSON object / String has been injected with untrusted data (e.g. inserted additional key), does GSON perform safe serialization that delimits and escapes untrusted data?

Please see this [link](http://www.hpenterprisesecurity.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/dotnet/json_injection.html) (though it's on C#) as an example of injected JSON.

Here's how I'm parsing the received data:

```
T object = gson.<T>fromJson(sampleString, modelObject);
```

I'm not really aware how a safe serialization or delimiting untrusted data works. Suggestion / reference related to this is much appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what "safe serialization" would mean in this context. For example, you might edit your question to provide a [mcve], where you show some JSON that "has been injected with untrusted data" along with your Java code that is using Gson to parse that JSON.

Comment: Please see updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gson is going to parse whatever is in `sampleString` and apply it your instance of `T`. `sampleString` is a string of JSON. Gson has no way of knowing whether that JSON "has been injected with untrusted data", because Gson does not know what is and is not "untrusted".

However, Gson is only going to pay attention to the fields defined on `T` and its superclasses. If `sampleString` is a JSON object, and somebody hacked that JSON to contain a key named `bogeyman`, and `T` does not have a `bogeyman` field (and has not inherited one), `bogeyman` will be ignored, because Gson has nowhere to put it.

Hence, make sure that `T` is written such that it only accepts valid keys. Perhaps `T` only *has* fields for valid keys, or you mark other fields as `transient`, or take other steps as outlined in [the user guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Excluding-Fields-From-Serialization-and-Deserialization).